# unable to install create-react-app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I am following https://hackernoon.com/simple-react-development-in-2017-113bd563691f
I am new to `React` ecosystem and I just now installed `Yarn`

```
➜  WebstormProjects yarn --version
0.23.2
```

Then I installed `created-react-app` as mentioned in the docs as

```
➜  WebstormProjects yarn global add create-react-app
yarn global v0.23.2
warning No license field
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Installed "create-react-app@1.3.0" with binaries:
      - create-react-app
warning No license field
✨  Done in 0.82s.
```

Then, I tried creating app

```
➜  WebstormProjects create-react-app myproject
zsh: command not found: create-react-app
```

Then, I headed over https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app and tried installing using `npm` as

```
➜  WebstormProjects npm install -g create-react-app

npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /Users/Harit.Himanshu/WebstormProjects/create-react-app
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.9.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "create-react-app"
npm ERR! node v7.9.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0

npm ERR! No name provided in package.json
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Harit.Himanshu/.npm/_logs/2017-04-15T03_06_22_478Z-debug.log
```

The `node` and `npm` versions I have are

```
➜  WebstormProjects node --version
v7.9.0
➜  WebstormProjects npm --version
4.2.0
➜  WebstormProjects
```

What mistake I am making?

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have a directory called `create-react-app` under this same path, would you...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on `npm`'s output, it's interpreting your command as an attempt to install a package contained in a local directory globally. You might want to try `rm -rf create-react-app && sudo npm i -g create-react-app` within that same directory.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to run the terminal with  Run as Administrator
2. Cd to ~ `cd ~`
3. Run the command `npm cache clean --force`
4. Then run the command `npm install -g npm@latest --force`
5. Now again run the command `npm cache clean --force`
6. Finally, run the command `npx create-react-app my-app`
7. If it works let me know, Used HYPER TERMINAL to install